# How to stop/hibernate GKE cluster in GCP?

Tags: cluster, google-kubernetes-engine, hibernation

In order to save costs, we would like to stop or hibernate an `Kubernetes GKE` cluster in `GCP cloud`.
I could not find any hint on this in documentation.

Did I miss something?

Comment: OK: I found a solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38323134/how-to-stop-gcloud-container-engine-clusters Thus can be closed.

Answer (score 1):

As OP mentioned in comment, there is possibility to start/stop GKE cluster using [resize](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/resizing-a-cluster) command from gcloud. However as new versions and features comes out, this command needs to be tuned.

In current default version (`1.15.12-gke.2`) GKE is using [Node Pools](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/node-pools). It allows you to have a few `node pools` and each of them can have different Image type, Machine configuration, disk size, etc.

Due to this, while you are resizing cluster you also need specify which `node pool` you want to resize.

```
gcloud container clusters resize cluster-name --node-pool pool-name \
    --num-nodes num-nodes
```

> `cluster-name`: the name of the cluster to resize.
>
> `pool-name`: the name of the node pool to resize.
>
> `num-node`s: the number of nodes in the pool in a zonal cluster. If you use multi-zonal or regional clusters, num-nodes is the number of nodes for each zone the node pools is in.

When you use this command you can increase or decrease numbers of nodes in your `node pool`. You don't need to worry that if you will resize your `node pools` to `0` you will delete/loss data in cluster, as `Master` is managed by google and when you will resize up `node pool` all configuration and deployed resources will be still there.

However there is another solution, to use [Cluster Autoscaler](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler).

> GKE's cluster autoscaler automatically resizes the number of nodes in a given node pool, based on the demands of your workloads. You don't need to manually add or remove nodes or over-provision your node pools. Instead, you specify a minimum and maximum size for the node pool, and the rest is automatic.

Comment: +1 I was looking for a reassurance that I would not lose configuration